# Multiple line chart with lines starting from different x-axis tickvalues

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, linechart

I want to draw a line chart for two years comparing data of months selected.

I want to show full-year (Jan-Dec) data for the last year, but I want to show data for the selected months (Mar-June) for the current year.

My current year graph instead of starting from March starts from Jan only. And, instead of a line from Mar-June, it draws from Jan-April for the current year.

[image]

How can I make the bold lines start from March-June instead of January-April ?

[image]

Comment: What's the data structure for the March to June series e.g. is it an array of objects with nulls for the months with no data e.g. `[{jan: null}, {feb: null}, {mar: 10}, {apr: 20}, {may: 30}, {jun: null} ... etc]` - you can see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747259/d3-non-continuous-line-chart-with-null-values-inside-an-object and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3

Comment: I edited the question with the date structure, for last year it comes from Jan-Dec 2020

Comment: Can you add your code - minimum of your x scale and line generator.